# Please verify that this function is continuous everywhere on its domain

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

In high school, I was taught the "naive" definition of continuity of a function. Consider

f(x) = x, where the domain of f = {x: 0 ≥ x ≥ 1} ∪ {x: 2 ≥ x ≥ 3}.

Back in high school, I would have thought that because there's a break in the graph, that f(x) is discontinuous. Now, after reading the definition of a continuous function in my real analysis book, I am convinced that this function is continuous everywhere on its domain. Am I correct?

Comment: I think defining $f$ and the domain of $f$ may be a shorthand for a more complex function. Rather than having separate entries in the function for $f(1.5) = undefined$. You are right that it would be more proper to define the function fully than use this shorthand.

Comment: Yes, totally correct.

Comment: @JoshG A more precise definition is that discontinuity and continuity are concepts that apply only to points in the domain of the function. For points outside the domain, the question doesn't even come up. However, "function is discontinuous if it's not defined at some point" is a very popular version.

Comment: Did you make a type in your domain?  I doubt you actually meant for the domain to be the empty set (which is what $\{0\ge x \ge 1\}\cup \{2 \ge x \ge 3\}$  is).  But yes, if the the domain is $\{x|0\le x \le 1\} \cup \{x| 2\le x \le 3\}$ then yes, it is continuous at all points in its domain.

Comment: OP here. After reading all the comments, I still think this is a function continuous everywhere on its domain. (I'm not even sure if saying that it's discontinuous at x = 1.5 makes any sense. You might as well say that it's discontinuous at x = 1.5,1.5,1.5 in R^3.) 

My textbook (paraphrased): Suppose x is a point in the domain of f. If, for every neighborhood V of f(x) there exists a neighborhood U of x such that if alpha is in the intersection of U and the domain of x, then f(alpha) is in V, f is continuous at alpha.

By this, my f(x) is continuous everywhere on its domain.

Answer (score 1):

You're right, this function is continuous, as you can easily verify using the definition of continuity in an analysis book.

But what about the "high school definition" of continuity? Of course it's not really a definition, but let's accept it for the moment as a kind of useful "intuitive definition" for pedagogical purposes.

That definition could easily be reformulated in a more useful and more general manner which applies to domains like the one in your post, something like this:

> Over any portion of the domain which has no break, there's also no break in the graph.

If one has a domain, like the one in your post, which is a union of some number $n$ of intervals with $n-1$ breaks in between them, one can be more precise, like this:

> Over any interval contained in the domain, there's no break in the graph.

Applying either one of these "definitions" (and using the correction suggested in the comment of @fleablood), over the first portion $\{x : 0 \le x \le 1\}$ of the domain the graph of $y=x$ has no break; then there's a break in the domain; and then, over the second portion $\{x | 2 \le x \le 3\}$ of the domain, the graph of $y=x$ also has no break. So the function is continuous.

Eventually, though, the "high school definition" is going to break down in an irretrievable manner, particularly for domains which are not just finite unions of intervals. Perhaps the simplest such domain is the set $\{0\} \cup \{\frac{1}{n} \mid n \in \mathbb N\}$. The analysis definition can tell us whether or not a function with this domain is continuous, but the "high school definition" would be useless.

Comment: The Cantor function (Cantor-Lebesgue function) is an(other) example of a function that is continuous everywhere on its domain and yet has no intervals. I'm not sure it pays to put too much time into working out a definition that ultimately fails. I'd rather tell students, "We're going to have an informal, incomplete notion of continuity. In later years, you can replace this idea with a better one. One step at a time."

Comment: I don't disagree with you regarding a definition that "ultimately fails", nonetheless I wanted to point out that even those who are naive should have the opportunity to know that this function is continuous.

Comment: I'm the OP. I had a very good math teacher in high school, where I was taught ("naive") calculus. I remember that we dealt with two types of "discontinuities": jump discontinuities (which are, indeed, discontinuities), and vertical asymptotes (which are not, in light of this discussion). I don't think we ever dealt with the question raised here, which is why I asked it.

Comment: Yes, my early experiences of continuity were similar. I'll add that I'm not particularly advocating revising the "high school definition", but still, I wanted to address your post from that point of view.